# How to convert a string into nested dictionaries in python (Generator expression)?

Tags: python, generator-expression

here is the input string:

```
s = 'Iva paper 10,Nelson pens 5,Oleg marker 3,Sasha paper 7,Mark envelope 20'
```

I would like to have an output like this:

```
{'Iva': {'paper': 10},
'Mark': {'envelope': 20},
'Nelson': {'pens': 5},
'Oleg': {'marker': 3},
'Sasha': {'paper': 7}}
```

the code that can do that is:

```
for k in s.split(','):
    v = k.split(' ')
    d[v[0]] = {v[1]: int(v[2])}
```

but the question is how can I do it using a ***Generator expression***?

If thee were 2 elements(`'paper 5,pen 6,...'`) I could do this

```
d = dict((k, int(v)) for k, v in (e.split(' ') for e in s.split(',')))
```

I wonder how we can do it in this case!

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
s = 'Iva paper 10,Nelson pens 5,Oleg marker 3,Sasha paper 7,Mark envelope 20'

g = dict((j, dict([(k, l)])) for i in s.split(',') for j, k, l in (i.split(' '),))

#{'Iva': {'paper': '10'}, 'Nelson': {'pens': '5'}, 'Oleg': {'marker': '3'}, 'Sasha': {'paper': '7'}, 'Mark': {'envelope': '20'}}
print(g)
```